# Calculating a transition probability in FSM

Tags: probability, transition-matrix, finite-state-machine

I have a Finite State Machine represented in following form:

```
[ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,] 
[ 4, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0,]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
```

Where each row represents a state (first row is `s0`, second one is `s1`, etc) and the values represent the probability of transitioning to the next state. For instance, `s0` has 50% chance of going to `s1` and 50% chance of going to `s5`.

How can I calculate probability of going from `s0` to `s3`? If these states did not have a loopback (you can go from `s0` to `s1` and then back to `s0` according to this matrix) answer would be trivial, but I am bit confused about how this loop or feedback changes the probabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if $s_2,s_3,s_4$ all absorb and that $s_2$ is inaccessible.

Let $p$ be the probability you want.  Then

$$p = \frac12\times\left(\frac49\times p +\frac29 \times 1 + \frac39 \times 0\right)+\frac12 \times 0$$  which is easy to solve for $p$

Comment: Hi. If I wanted to learn more about how you got to your answer what topic should I look into? I initially thought this was finite state machines as used in computer science, while similar doesn't seem to be an exact match.

Comment: @uriDium I was treating this as a Markov chain when the rows which were all zero represented absorbing states,

Comment: I thought as much. Then do we need to determine the stabilizing matrix? Is that how we get to the formula you provided?

Comment: @uriDium This is not an ergodic Markov chain so there is not a unique stable distribution.  Instead, starting from $s_0$, you either (a) go to $s_1$ and then (a1) go back to $s_0$ to start again or (a2) go to $s_3$ successfully or (a3) go to the absorbing $s_4$, or (b) go to the absorbing $s_5$. Hence the expression

Comment: It appears to me that you were able to pull out a formula fairly easily by just examining the matrix. How did you go from Matrix to formula? Or can you point me in the right direction (which topics should I be reading). I have been stuck on a similar problem for a few days now. Thanks so much for your help. (I did a BCom Computer Science, so I don't have as much theory as others, economics was my other major)

Comment: @uriDium It was simply the logic in that statement and saying $\frac1{0+1+0+0+0+1}=\frac12$ and $\frac{4}{4+ 0+0+ 2+ 3+ 0 }=\frac49$ etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138683/discussion-between-uridium-and-henry).

Comment: @uriDium - I do not use chat - sorry

Comment: No problem. I was just prompted to by stack exchange. I totally understand how to arrive at the fractions. That is easy. it is the total of the weight emmiting from a state divided by that edge's weight. I am trying to understand how you arrived at the parts within the brackets. Are you mulitplying $\frac{3}{9}$ by zero and $\frac{2}{9}$ by 1 because we assuming that was the outcome that we were interested in?

If we wanted to find S4 would I multiply $\frac{2}{9}$ by 0 and $\frac{3}{9}$ by 1?

Comment: @uriDium Yes - the $\frac29$ is "(a2) go to $s_3$ successfully" and the $\frac39$ is "(a3) go to the absorbing $s_4$"

Comment: OK almost there, almost have it. Thank you so much for your time. When you have $\frac{4p}{9}$ where does that p come from. 

And I am assuming that the final $\frac{1}{2}$ comes from the probablity of going to S5 from S0 and it having not occurred so multiply that by zero.

Comment: @uriDium the $\frac49$ is "(a1) go back to $s_0$ ..." while the $p$ is "... to start again"

Comment: Sorry to bother again. Am I correct in saying that I cannot brute force this by repeatedly multiplying out the transition matrix because there are absorbing states. If I wanted to find the stationary distribution then I must find the left eigenvector of the transition matrix?

Comment: @uriDium If you turned this into  an actual transition matrix (e.g. each row summing to $1$) and then raised it to a high power, then that would enable you to brute force this. There is a slight issue with periodicity, but that goes away as the states affected here are transient.

Comment: I did that with working out the total number of obs and then dividing. But there are rows where the are no obs. Those rows I cannot convert to 1 or am I missing a trick?

Comment: @uriDium I would assume $s_2$, $s_3$, and $s_4$ are all absorbing states and put a $1$ in the appropriate places

Comment: Got it. By setting the Transition S5 to S5 to 1 (S5 for example) it is still absorbing but raising to the power doesn't leak out until it hits zero. Thank you

Comment: @uriDium - yes (though the last one is $s_4$ since the first is $s_0$)